# How does it work for Python's copy and memory system?

Tags: python

How does it work for Python's memory reference?

When I tried a program on a matrix, I used nested list. Then I found the original data was mutated, even I copied it. I tried several way. Finally I used copy.deepcopy() to solve the problem. So what's the meaning of Python's copy and reference function. How could we avoid such s-(problems).

```py
data = [
[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
]
# data1 = data.copy() # нет
# data1 = data[:] # нет
# data1 = list(data) # нет
# data1 = list(data) # нет
# data1 = copy.copy(data) # нет
# for all of above five, data1 will change with data, even they differ from ID
```

For these five, we shall see:

```py
data[0][0] = 0
print(id(data))
print(id(data1))
print(data)
print(data1)
# Out:
# 4450009608
# 4450115528
# [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
# [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Thus we have to use deepcopy, such a little pit.

Comment: think of copy as "shallow copy", it makes a copy of the outer list **which is full of references to other lists**, this is why you need "deep copy" to copy the inner lists as well. with shallow copy you could have done `data[0] = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` without changing the other list

Answer (score 1):

This is explained (with more detail) in [the documentation of the copy module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html):

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
>   compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
>   class instances):
>
> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original. A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then,
>   recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
>   original.

All the attempts you made in your first example only create shallow copies.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I tried thinking this way, turned out lists nested in that list are also needed copying. And different IDs does not mean they are "different" in the memory. This is really tricky.

Comment: @KellyHwong Different ids *does* mean two values are different in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This `data1 = data.copy()` and this `data1 = data[:]` both make copies, but only *one level deep*. Below the first level, only references are copied. Which is why you are not seeing what you expect at the second level.

Answer (score 0):

The `id`s of `data` and `data1` will be different when for example using:

```
data1 = list(data)
```

But the inner lists will still point to the same objects and have the same `id`s, that's why you have to use `deepcopy` to copy the whole contents of the original `data` to new objects.